# WebStorm reports an error on 'mat-sort-header requires value'

Tags: angular-material, webstorm, angular12

I'm using Angular Material `mat-soft-header` attribute which works fine, but WebStorm reports an error that 'mat-sort-header requires value'.

By the way, I faced with this issue in different projects, so as I understand this is a very common problem in many projects.

Here is an example code

```html
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort>
  ...
  <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Name</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.name}} </td>
  </ng-container>
  
</table>
```

Also attaching the error message by WebStorm:

[image]

Can anybody help to understand and resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

Nothing is wrong with your code, it's a bug in the IDE. Please vote for [WEB-57358](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-57358/Angular-Material-mat-sort-header-without-value-causes-mat-sort-header-requires-value-error) to be notified on any progress with it